Copying columns in pandas
I want to compare two or more columns and place the larger and smaller values ​​in a new column.
First, I copied the two columns and then changed the values ​​of the rows that met the conditions.
However, there is a problem where row values ​​that do not meet the conditions are changed to nan.

How not to change to nan
How to do this all at once (if possible)

sample:
import pandas as pd

a = [
    {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 5},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 1},
    {'a': 3.5, 'b': 15, 'c': 9},
    {'a': 2.1, 'b': 5, 'c': 8},
    {'a': 0.1, 'b': 1, 'c': 5},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.loc[:, ['Big', 'Small']] = df[['a', 'b']].values
print(df.head())
df.loc[df['a'] < df['b'], ['Big', 'Small']] = df[['b', 'a']]
print(df.head())
>>
     a     b  c  Big  Small
0  5.0  10.0  5  5.0   10.0
1  4.0   0.5  1  4.0    0.5
2  3.5  15.0  9  3.5   15.0
3  2.1   5.0  8  2.1    5.0
4  0.1   1.0  5  0.1    1.0

     a     b  c  Big  Small
0  5.0  10.0  5  NaN    NaN
1  4.0   0.5  1  4.0    0.5
2  3.5  15.0  9  NaN    NaN
3  2.1   5.0  8  NaN    NaN
4  0.1   1.0  5  NaN    NaN

i want:
>>
      a     b  c  Big  Small
*0  5.0  10.0  5 10.0    5.0*
 1  4.0   0.5  1  4.0    0.5
*2  3.5  15.0  9 15.0    3.5*
*3  2.1   5.0  8  5.0    2.1*
*4  0.1   1.0  5  1.0    0.1*


This question is similar to: Get max value of 3 columns from pandas DataFrame?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use numpy to compare
df['Big'] = np.where(df['a'] >= df['b'], df['a'], df['b'])
df['Small'] = np.where(df['a'] < df['b'], df['a'], df['b'])

Output
     a     b  c   Big  Small
0  5.0  10.0  5  10.0    5.0
1  4.0   0.5  1   4.0    0.5
2  3.5  15.0  9  15.0    3.5
3  2.1   5.0  8   5.0    2.1
4  0.1   1.0  5   1.0    0.1


You should use a mask on both sides and convert to array to avoid column alignment:
df.loc[:, ['Big', 'Small']] = df[['a', 'b']].values
m = df['a'] < df['b']
df.loc[m, ['Big', 'Small']] = df.loc[m, ['b', 'a']].values

Or, better, use mask to create the columns directly:
df[['Big', 'Small']] = df[['a', 'b']].mask(df['a']<df['b'],
                                           df[['b', 'a']].values)

Finally, if you just want to sort the two columns:
import numpy as np
df[['Big', 'Small']] = np.sort(df[['a', 'b']], axis=1)[:, ::-1]

Output:
     a     b  c   Big  Small
0  5.0  10.0  5  10.0    5.0
1  4.0   0.5  1   4.0    0.5
2  3.5  15.0  9  15.0    3.5
3  2.1   5.0  8   5.0    2.1
4  0.1   1.0  5   1.0    0.1


Thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, np.where was faster, so I adopted that method.

@django.seolpyo.com yes, numpy is lower level, but if you have more than 2 columns it becomes combersome (and slower) to have one line of code per column. Also, a shortcoming of np.where, especially if you handle multiple columns at once (which was your requirement #2), is that if forces a common dtype (ie. if you have numbers and strings, it will convert all to strings). I prefer to use pandas functions when possible.
